# Force iOS Device to Download App

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-developer

I wonder if it is possible to force an iOS Device to download an app.

I have a 1 Year Apple Developer Account and i can create Profiles.

I heard that if Users install your Profile Configuration you can do some actions.
Now i thought instead of connecting a Device over USB to PC and Load an IPA to the Device , to Force a Device UDID (with a Installed Profile) to download an App without having it to be connected to pc

Comment: Use Fabric and Crashlytics. It does this for free. :-)

Comment: My idea is to push-download to an Apple TV 4 so it installs a signed version of Kodi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this with a normal app.
However you may want to look into:

1. Entreprise apps. If you distribute an enterprise app, and setup MDM (mobile device management) you can push an app to a device
2. MDM, if you own the set of devices, you can setup mobile device management on them and push app updates.
3. You could look at solutions like rollout.io which provide a wrapper for the JS bridge into iOS to allow you to deploy simple updates and bug fixes to a live app.

You cannot, force push an app or update to a live app store user.